# gulp-jasmine gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, gulp

I've started trying to learn javascript unit testing with a test project.
The project has a gulpfile.js at the root of it that contains this:
'use strict';

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
     config: {
         'dependencies': {
             'gulp-jasmine': '*'
          }
     },
     camelize: true
});
gulp.task('jstest', function() {
    return gulp.src(['js_unit_tests/*'])
        .pipe(plugins.jasmine({ verbose: true, showStackTrace: true }));
});
```

The only file in the js_unit_tests directory is grid-tests.js and it looks like this:

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/angular.js" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/underscore.js" />
///<reference path="../app.js" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/Components/Grid/grid.js" />

describe('GridController Test', function () {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    describe('GridCtrl', function () {
        var scope,
            controller,
            timeout;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $timeout) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller;
            timeout = $timeout;
        }));

        it('should initialize vm values without scope isolate properties being provided', function () {
            var cont = controller('GridCtrl', { $scope: scope, $timeout: timeout });

            expect(scope.actions).toBeUndefined();
            expect(scope.data).toBeUndefined();
            expect(scope.settings).toBeUndefined();

            expect(cont.actions instanceof Array).toBeTruthy();
            expect(typeof (cont.data)).toBe('object');
            expect(typeof (cont.settings)).toBe('object');
            expect(cont.gridActions instanceof Array).toBeTruthy();
            expect(cont.columnDefinitions instanceof Array).toBeTruthy();
            expect(cont.rows instanceof Array).toBeTruthy();
            expect(cont.selectedColumnDefinitionId).toBe('');
            expect(cont.selectedRowId).toBe(0);
            expect(typeof (cont.onclick)).toBe('function');
            expect(typeof (cont.onblur)).toBe('function');
            expect(cont.sortedColumn).toBe('');
            expect(cont.sortDirection).toBe('none');
            expect(typeof (cont.sort)).toBe('function');
        });
    });
});
```

All of the tests run and pass using resharper. Executing the above gulp task though gives me this:

```
<dir>\Experiment\AngularUIComponents\AngularUIComponents>gulp
 jstest
[16:40:43] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\a\Experiment\AngularUIComponents\AngularUICo
mponents\gulpfile.js
[16:40:43] Starting 'jstest'...
Running 1 specs.

GridController Test
    encountered a declaration exception: failed

Failures:
1) GridController Test encountered a declaration exception
1.1) TypeError: object is not a function

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.008 seconds
[16:40:43] 'jstest' errored after 62 ms
[16:40:43] Error in plugin 'gulp-jasmine'
Message:
    Tests failed
```

I can't figure out what I have configured improperly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you figure it out what was causing this ?